# Roslyn - Interface member not found using FindImplementationForInterfaceMember

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Could somebody please explain why the interface implementation of M1 in class A is not found using the 'FindImplementationForInterfaceMember()' method?

All variables have a reference to a symbol, except 'am1' which is null.

```
            string source = @"
namespace Lib
{
    public interface IA<T>
    {
        void M1();
    }

    public class A<T> : IA<T>
    {
        public void M1() { }
    }
}
";
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation")
            .AddSyntaxTrees(CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source));

        var global = compilation.GlobalNamespace;
        var lib = global.GetMembers("Lib").OfType<INamespaceSymbol>().Single();
        var ia = lib.GetTypeMembers("IA").OfType<ITypeSymbol>().Single();
        var a = lib.GetTypeMembers("A").OfType<ITypeSymbol>().Single();

        var iam1 = ia.GetMembers("M1").OfType<IMethodSymbol>().Single();
        var am1 = a.FindImplementationForInterfaceMember(iam1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ia` (and therefore its member `am1`) is an *open* (or unconstructed) generic type, with no type parameter specified.

Classes (and their methods) implement *closed* (constructed) generic types, which specify a specific type for the type parameter(s).

Therefore, `FindImplementationForInterfaceMember()` can only ever return anything if you pass it an method on a closed interface.

In your particular case, you need to construct a closed interface by specifying your class' type parameter (because the class implements `IA<T>` with its own `T`).  Had your class implemented differently (eg, `: IA<List<T>>`), it would be even more complicated.